# How to change the range of years from sfWidgetFormFilterDate?

Tags: filter, widget, symfony-1.4

In my field `expiration_date` from my filter, I want to change the range of year (to begin in 2013 and not in 2008) of the select box. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I do this:

> ```
>  $years = range(date('Y') - 1, date('Y') + 6);
>
>   $this->widgetSchema['expiration_date'] = new
>   sfWidgetFormFilterDate(array(
>               'from_date'     => new sfWidgetFormDate(array('format' => '%day%-%month%-%year%','years' => array_combine($years, $years))), 
>               'to_date'       => new sfWidgetFormDate(array('format' => '%day%-%month%-%year%','years' => array_combine($years, $years))), 
>               'with_empty'    => false, 
>               'template'      =>'du %from_date% to %to_date%'));
> ```

So the date changes dynamically.

Comment: Of course. That's up to your specs. I just gave you the general idea

Comment: Yes, it is just for help another person if it wants to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

Send the years as options to the date widgeds (from_date and/or to_date). Something like this (not tested):

```
$this->widgetSchema['date'] = new sfWidgetFormFilterDate(
                  array(
                     'from_date'=>new sfWidgetFormDate(array('years' => array('2013' => '2013', '2014' => '2014)),
                     'to_date'    =>new sfWidgetFormDate(array('years' => array('2013' => '2013', '2014' => '2014)),
                     )
               );
```

See more about sfWidgetFormDate [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWidgetFormDate).

Comment: Hard coded years aren't a great idea. Guess what will happen after 2014?

Comment: Quote: "Something like this". Is up to him how to write the years. I can think of at least 3 ideas for that. But, again, it's up to his specs. I think his problem was how to send those to the widget, not the actual years (either is 2013 or 2100)